# Dynamically changing the rectangle size android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm making an application which can crop the image of the person. The layout of my application will give a better description

[image]

Here the rectangle will be used to capture the image defined by its length and width. The rectangle is movable. How would I go about re-sizing the rectangle. For eg. in WhatsApp when you touch the region inside the rectangle, the rectangle moves. If you touch the  edges of rectangle, it provides the ability to re-size image suitable for cropping. So, I have 2 questions. 1) How to receive Touch events on edges of rectangle and 2) How would I re-size my rectangle. I'm using canvas to draw my rectangle. The code for this is as follows:

```
public class CustomView extends Views
{


public CustomView(Context context) 
 {
       super(context);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
 {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);;
       paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 300, paint);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the OnTouchListener and check in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` if you touch the rectangle and modify right, left, bottom and top of rectangle in `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

I provided a not tested example:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private float left=0,right = 300, top = 0, bottom = 300;

    public CustomView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {
            float oldX, oldY;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                boolean touch = false;
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        touch = isTouchBorderRect();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        touch = false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (touch){
                            float newX = event.getRawX();
                            float newY = event.getRawY();
                            float deltaX = newX-oldX;
                            float deltaY = newY-oldY;

                            left-=deltaX;
                            right +=deltaX;
                            bottom += deltaY;
                            top -= deltaY;

                        }
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);;
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    }

}
```

In `isTouchBorderRect()` method you should check if you have touched the rectangle.

This code is not tested but show the idea that you want to develop.